# How can i call javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

here i am trying to call the javascript function onclick of anchor tag. When i am calling the function onclick, nothing is happening..

I even have the alert in my javascript function, even alert is also not happening.

here is my code:

```
document.writeln('<td><img class="rteImage" src="' + imagesPath + 'code.gif" width="25" height="24" alt="Code" title="Code" onClick="applyTag(document.getElementById("rte1"),"code")"></td>');
```

javascript function:

```
function applyTag(obj, tag)
{
    wrapText(obj, '<'+tag+'>', '</'+tag+'>');
    alert("hello 1");
};

function wrapText(obj, beginTag, endTag)
{
alert("hello 2");
    if(typeof obj.selectionStart == 'number')
    {
        var start = obj.selectionStart;
        var end   = obj.selectionEnd;   
        obj.value = obj.value.substring(0, start) + beginTag + obj.value.substring(start, end) + endTag + obj.value.substring(end, obj.value.length);
    }
    else if(document.selection)
    {
        obj.focus();
        var range = document.selection.createRange();
        if(range.parentElement() != obj) return false;
        if(typeof range.text == 'string')
        document.selection.createRange().text = beginTag + range.text + endTag;
    }
    else
    obj.value += text;
};
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: what is being logged in console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont escape the double quotes then as soon as the first double quotes will be encountered, your onclick statement will come to end causing javascript error.

So Instead of this

```
document.writeln('<td><img class="rteImage" src="' + imagesPath + 'code.gif" width="25" height="24" alt="Code" title="Code" onClick="applyTag(document.getElementById("rte1"),"code")"></td>');
```

**you should use**

```
document.writeln('<td><img class="rteImage" src="' + imagesPath + 'code.gif" width="25" height="24" alt="Code" title="Code" onClick="applyTag(document.getElementById(\'rte1\'),\'code\')"></td>');
```

Comment: I'm really confused. This answer doesn't even work. The backslashes are meaningless in this string since it's single-quoted, and even if they _were_ being outputed HTML/XML doesn't let you escape quotes with backslashes. Why was it upvoted and accepted?

Comment: @DaoWen the string is single quoted, it tries to display html element, but when the element is interpreted by browser it will see onclick="applyTag(document.getElementById(\"rte1\"),\"code\")" . Now since onclick uses double quotes here we need to escape it

Comment: Did you try it? I did and **it doesn't work** for two reasons. First, the escaped `\"` is interpreted by the _JavaScript string_ to mean `"`, so the actual output becomes `onclick="applyTag(document.getElementById("rte1"),"code")"`, which is _exactly the same_ as before. Second, HTML/XML use `&`-escaped "entities" for escape characters, not backslash. Even if you got the backslashes to show up in the output by using `\\"`, that wouldn't actually escape the quotes. Please try running the code you posted and let me know if I'm wrong.

Comment: You're welcome...? Now your answer basically matches mine—but at least it's no longer both _accepted_ and _wrong_. In the future you might want to test the code that you post. I also expected that Pandora would have tested your solution before accepting your answer... Hence my confusion.

Comment: @DaoWen I have used same method but in little different fashion and it worked

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have a problem with nesting your quotes:

```
document.write('... onClick="applyTag(document.getElementById("rte1"),"code")"> ...')
```

The easiest way to fix that would probably be to use `'` instead and escape them (since you're generating this with a single-quoted string to document.write):

```
document.write('... onClick="applyTag(document.getElementById(\'rte1\'),\'code\')"> ...')
```